# Haskell: GHCi treats Ctrl-Y like Ctrl-Z

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskeline

According to the haskeline [documentation](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/KeyBindings), typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> should pop the most recent entry from the kill-ring (e.g. the line I just deleted via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). I'm finding that instead, it suspends the REPL, as if I'd typed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

As a clumsy workaround, I've found that typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> pops from the kill ring as a plain <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> is supposed to do.

Is this a know bug, or is something else at play? Can I fix it? I'm running GHC version 8.0.2.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm running GHCi via stack (e.g. `stack ghci`), and I brew installed stack (macOS).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Stack is irrelevant, but you should report the GHC version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mac OS terminals/ttys have a concept of a "dsusp" or "delayed suspend" key, and Ctrl-Y is the usual key assigned.  At the tty level, when a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> is read, it acts a little like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  The difference is that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> causes an immediate suspend when it's typed; <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> causes the suspend when the underlying process tries to read characters and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> marker pops up in the input stream.

(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is usually assigned to the "lnext" key, which skips terminal processing by making the next key "literal", which is why <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> works.)

Ideally, GHCi would check for "dsusp" functionality (it doesn't exist on Linux, for example) and disable it if it's detected, but it looks like it's not doing this.

In the meantime, you can disable your "dsusp" key by running:

```
stty dsusp undef
```

before you launch GHCi.  Sticking this in your ".bashrc" and/or ".profile" is a good idea, since the functionality is largely useless.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm curious why this never impeded Ctrl-Y yank behavior in Bash. I guess when I'm already in the parent shell, it doesn't make sense to suspend the current job?

Comment: Well, Bash contains specific code to prevent Ctrl-Y (or Ctrl-Z) from having an effect at the shell prompt itself.  If it didn't do this, Bash would suspend like any other process (and would probably just freeze up in the absence of a parent process prepared to handle it).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for clarifying.